# php how can i include internal page by url?

Tags: include

for example my website is "myweb.com". how can i do opration like following.

```
include(http://myweb.com/file);
```

this is an internal URL.

for example i want to include

```
http://myweb.com/process.php?action=update
```

this is not a file

```
 "?action=update"
```

thus how can i do this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the base PHP file--process.php--and then pass the variables you want from there. I would do this by wrapping the code of process.php that uses $action in a function. Then, you can include it and pass the information to that function:

```
include('process.php');
process_function("update");
```

There is also an OOP way of doing this if process.php defines a class with a constructor that you can pass the needed $update variable, e.g.:

```
include('process.php');
$process = new Process("update");
```